# How to. domain works?

Tags: dns, url-shortener

Can somebody explain why and how "to." domain works? It's not usual.

http://to./

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work? Your link is broken.

Comment: It does work, it depends on your browser AND your DNS provider for whether it will work. Chrome + Google DNS works appropriately.

Comment: Yeah, I get a DNS error.

Comment: DNS isn't *related* to programming?  I beg to disagree.

Comment: @Nick: No, it isn't *related* to programming any more than any arbitrary networking component. I wouldn't consider a question about how a router works to be any more programming-related. That's why we have sites like superuser.com and serverfault.com

Comment: @Adam Robinson - I'm writing a console in c# managing our DNS for dev environments right now, so I disagree.

Comment: @Nick: Does that mean that if I'm writing a word processor in C# then suddenly the particulars of English spelling and grammar are now related to programming?

Comment: @Adam - What does it matter if I invented google unless I can setup DNS correctly?  For the web world, it's a direct dependency we have.  Your word processor will work without spell check, DNS isn't optional, and knowing how it works is often a necessity.

Comment: @Nick: DNS is certainly optional. Nothing about the internet in any way requires you to use anything other than an IP address. DNS is a convenience that we've adopted (certainly a good one), but not a requirement in the strictest sense of the word.

Comment: @Adam - I disagree, show me a web app on the internet that's used via only IP.  A common example: I have 2 sites on the same machine, same IP only differentiated by host headers you need more than just an IP.  Whether it's local or DNS, saying you **only** need an IP isn't accurate.

Comment: @Nick: And show me a mainstream word processor without spellcheck. I never said that it was conventional (or even practical), but your statement that it's a requirement is incorrect. I'm not going to continue to debate whether a purely networking-related topic is on topic for SO. If that's the opinion of the community, then the topic will be reopened.

Comment: @Adam - I have Notepad2 open right now.  I'm not comparing just mainstream, my example is 99.99% of the internet.

Comment: @Nick: At the risk of continuing this, I'll refer you to http://bit.ly/8B1scH for a well-written definition of a word processor. Notepad2 would be a *text editor*.

Answer (score 2):

is equivalent to http://to/  The site is simply hosted on the top level domain `to`.

The same could be hosted at http://com/ if whoever is in charge of `com` wanted to.  You typically see it with the `.` like http://to./ so it doesn't resolve to a local machine named `to` or get resolved by the browser incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` is superfluous—the actual domain is http://to/, but Firefox, at the very least, converts that to http://www.to.com/, and that's not what we're going for at all. Additional `.` characters on each side don't mean anything, and appending a `.` lets the browser know that that's all we want. http://.to/ should also work, but Firefox seems to want to point it to http://www.to/.

`.to` is a top-level domain that belongs to Tonga, and the company in charge of allocating domain names has created one with no second-level domain, which is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the [Tonga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.to) top-level domain? If so, it's just another TLD for a specific country.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're asking about  [the `.to` ccTLD for the country of Tonga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.to).